# Linux VCP driver for ARM processor

Tags: drivers

I need Linux VCP driver file for FTDI cable (USB to TTL converter: C232HM-DDHSL-0)for ARM processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can download drivers from the [FTDI website](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm).

Comment: Hi Sampath, Thanks for your response. I checked in the website also, but there is no linux VCP drivers for ARM CPU.